# Pass data to Angular Dialog

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I have a function for a file upload which is like this

```
openUploadPdfSolved = (i) => {
    this.dialog.open(UploadPdfComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      data: {
        addPdfEntry: this.addPdfEntry,
      }
    });
  }
```

everything is working just fine but how can I pass the `i` into the `addPdfEntry`? As this is important to have.

Comment: what prevents you from adding another property to `data` that holds `i`?

Comment: the addPdfEntry wont recognize it and will only check the data that is coming from the upload component.

Comment: Seems like a implementation problem then, not a `how do I do it?` question.

Comment: What about `data: {
    addPdfEntry: this.addPdfEntry,
 i: i
}` and access it using `data.i `

Comment: `bind`? `addPdfEntry: this.addPdfEntry.bind(i)`.. I hate `bind` but for the limited picture I have, it can work..